# Keep progress dialog on top

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have an application with a progress dialog (created by `pd = new ProgressDialog(ActivityName.this); ... pd.show();`) Everything works just fine but if I click/tap around the dialog, it is closed and the activity content gets to front of the view (the process handled by the dialog keeps running as expected - and the dialog reappears if I change screen orientation).

Is there any way to keep the dialog on top (i.e. disable taps outside the dialog)?

Note: in the emulator, the clicks are disabled as expected, on a real phone (SGII, A4.0.4), tapping on the progress dialog's surroundings closes the dialog...

Code:

```
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DownloaderActivity.this); 
mProgressDialog.setMessage(DownloaderActivity.this.getString(R.string.downloadin‌​gfile));      
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false); 
mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);   
mProgressDialog.show(); … mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: The code is as follows:
`mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DownloaderActivity.this);
mProgressDialog.setMessage(DownloaderActivity.this.getString(R.string.downloadingfile));
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
mProgressDialog.show();
…
mProgressDialog.dismiss();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the setCanceledOnTouchOutside() method to false. 
[Take a look at the android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29)

If you have done that and it's still not working, it's probably a bug with the android system. One way to get around this have an onCancelListener so that when the dialog is cancelled, the code in the listener checks to see if the progress is done. If not, it could relaunch the Dialog.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would've expected to be the default behavior, but the opposite seems to be true.